# Android Text to Image issue

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have the code for text to image in android application and it is successfully converting the text to image and saving to a local location in SD card. What problem i am facing is that it is not converting the complete text to image. Here is the text i am supplying to textview "this is t ashdf asdhfj sdhkfh shd jshd hsdhfsdjkhfksdjfhsdlhfksldhfklh shdkfjhsdkj hfsdjk kdjhfsk djhfskldh shdjkfhk sjhdfkh". Here is what it converts to image [image]

Here is my code

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60);

    tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    tv.setText("this is t ashdf asdhfj sdhkfh shd jshd hsdhfsdjkhfksdjfhsdlhfksldhfklh shdkfjhsdkj hfsdjk kdjhfsk djhfskldh shdjkfhk sjhdfkh ");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Bitmap testB;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TickerTask(), 1000,25);
    testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getText().length(), 20, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(testB);

    tv.layout(0, 0, 800, 30);
    tv.draw(c);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
    x=40;
    iv.setPadding(x, 0, 0, 0);
    iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    iv.setImageBitmap(testB);
    iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    //Bitmap bitmap = testB;
    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");

    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success"+tv.getText().length(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the complete the text to an image you have to get the width of the text inside the textview not the textview itself. So here is how you can get the width of text.

```
    string texting="Some Text";
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(texting,0,texting.length(),bounds);
    int heights= bounds.height();
    int widths = bounds.width();
```

Now you can use the above width and height to create the bitmap and the complete text (no matter how long or small) will be converted to image.

Answer (score 0):

change this row:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60);
```

To this:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

To paint directly you can try this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setTextSize(30);
canvas.drawText("Style.FILL", 75, 110, paint);
```

Comment: Issue is not displaying. Issue is the size of the image should cover the whole text and show in the image saved. testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getText().length(), 20, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); This is the main issue that how should i specify the generated image size exactly same as text size.

Comment: you trying to take an image from a view (TextView in this case). if this view doesn't have enough space to hold all it's content then the image that will be taken will be of the content that had space to be shown. so you have to enlarge your TextView so it's could hold all the content.

Comment: What if the text is bigger than the TextView. I have to convert whole text to image. Is there a way i can supply the text directly to the canvas

Comment: check this link: http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/ to paint text directly to canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is in about width of your `TextView`.Your method convert drawing area of your view  to  a bitmap.If a part of your text be hidden,really is not drawn in drawing area. Why you do not get text from `TextView` and write it to a canvas?You can use this method:

```
canvas.drawText();
```

sample code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);

paint.setTextSize(20);

canvas.drawText("Hello Android! Fill...", 50, 230, paint);
```

Comment: Can you suggest me on how can i directly supply text to canvas so it can convert the whole text as image ?

Comment: Thanks for your code, Can you please edit and merge your code with my code? I am quit confused and want the text to be dynamic from a user input and convert it to image with exact width.